# SQLite create view from inner join with multiple conditons

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

Currently I am storing the results of some simulations in `SQLite3` tables with the following structure

```
Table: radiation
id, timestamp,           surface_total_shortwave, cell_id
1 , 2010-01-01 09:00:00, 3.5,                     1 
2 , 2010-01-01 10:00:00, 2.5,                     1 
3 , 2010-01-01 11:00:00, 10.0,                    1 
4 , 2010-01-01 12:00:00, 6.5,                     1 
5 , 2010-01-01 09:00:00, 2.5,                     2 
6 , 2010-01-01 10:00:00, 1.5,                     2 
7 , 2010-01-01 11:00:00, 10.0,                    2 
8 , 2010-01-01 12:00:00, 5.5,                     2 
.., ..................., .....,    .
100 , 2010-01-01 09:00:00, 1.5,                   34 
101 , 2010-01-01 10:00:00, 1.5,                   34 
102 , 2010-01-01 11:00:00, 4.0,                   34 
103 , 2010-01-01 12:00:00, 3.5,                   34 
104 , 2010-01-01 09:00:00, 1.5,                   45 
105 , 2010-01-01 10:00:00, 2.5,                   45 
106 , 2010-01-01 11:00:00, 7.0,                   45 
107 , 2010-01-01 12:00:00, 2.5,                   45 
.., ..................., .....,    .
```

Actual create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE cfd(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time DATETIME, u, cell_id integer)
```

For each `cell_id` I have the same number of timestamps.

I need to subtract the time series for a list of (cell1 - cell2) combinations, assign it to cell1 and create a `view` that the user can interrogate.

For example:

```
cell1 = 1 and cell2 = 34
cell1 = 2 and cell2 = 45 (duplicates are possible for cell2)
```

For one single cell combination I do

```
create view ds as
select time1, (sts1 - sts2) as sts, cell_id from
    (select time as time1, cell_id, surface_total_shortwave as sts1 from radiation where cell_id = 1)
    inner join
    (select time as time2, surface_total_shortwave as sts2 from radiation where cell_id = 34)
    on time1 = time2
```

How can I extend this query when I have a mapping like

```
(cell1, cell2)
(1, 34)
(2, 45)
(..., ...)
```

The resulting table, assuming that the mapping is only for the 2 cells above (1 -> 34) and (2 -> 45) would be the following

```
Table: radiation
id, timestamp,           sts, cell_id
1 , 2010-01-01 09:00:00, 2.0,                     1 
2 , 2010-01-01 10:00:00, 1.0,                     1 
3 , 2010-01-01 11:00:00, 6.0,                     1 
4 , 2010-01-01 12:00:00, 3.0,                     1 
5 , 2010-01-01 09:00:00, 1.0,                     2 
6 , 2010-01-01 10:00:00, -1.0,                    2 
7 , 2010-01-01 11:00:00, 3.0,                     2 
8 , 2010-01-01 12:00:00, 3.0,                     2
```

EDIT
It seems that a possible solution could be to create a temporary table to store the mapping

```
Table: mapping    
idx, cell1, cell2
1,   1    , 34
2,   2    , 45
.., ..., ...
```

Now I can rewrite the query in this way

```
select time1, (sts1 - sts2) as sts, cell1_id, cell2_id from
    (select time as time1, cell_id as cell1_id, surface_total_shortwave as sts1 from radiation where cell_id in (1, 2))
    inner join
    (select time as time2, cell_id as cell2_id, surface_total_shortwave as sts2 from radiation where cell_id in (34, 45))
    on time1 = time2 and cell1_id = (select mapping.cell1 from mapping where mapping.cell2 = cell2_id)
```

Comment: Please show the desired result for your example.

Comment: I have edited the question and updated it with my current attempt

Comment: I have edited again with actual numbers

Comment: Please move the answer into an actual answer.

Comment: Is the number of mappings small and fixed?

Comment: There could be a few (no more than 10) mappings and each one of them is fixed. The size of each mapping could be in the order of 10,000 records, but typically between 100 and 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate multiple queries:

```
CREATE VIEW ds AS

SELECT time,
       r1.surface_total_shortwave - r2.surface_total_shortwave AS sts,
       r1.cell_id
FROM radiation AS r1
JOIN radiation AS r2 USING (time)
WHERE (r1.cell_id, r2.cell_id) = (1, 34)

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
...
WHERE (r1.cell_id, r2.cell_id) = (2, 45);
```

Alternatively, use a single query with all cell comparisons:

```
CREATE VIEW ds AS
SELECT time,
       r1.surface_total_shortwave - r2.surface_total_shortwave AS sts,
       r1.cell_id
FROM radiation AS r1
JOIN radiation AS r2 USING (time)
WHERE (r1.cell_id, r2.cell_id) = (1, 34)
   OR (r1.cell_id, r2.cell_id) = (2, 45);
```

(Both queries require proper indexes to be efficient. Which one is faster depends on the data; you have to measure it yourself.)

Using a temporary table for the mappings is possible, but worthwhile only if there any many more mappings.

Comment: Brilliant and elegant. I am going with the second option. I am generating the query programmatically so it quite easy to add multiple conditions